# upload a file using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have found the upload button and clicked on it but now I cant find a way to send the path of file which should be uploaded. here is the html code:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;"><input id="file" type="file" name="File" size="42" style="width:300px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;"></div>
```

it would be appreciated if somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

the file is stored in the `value` of the element so you can use:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id("file").value = "C://your_file.txt"

# or send keys

driver.find_element_by_id("file").send_keys("C://your_file.txt")
```

Comment: ```python

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="file"]"}
```

Comment: That means the tag you showed in the question is not present in the page

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code -

```
// Imports needed.
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

time.sleep(2)
Upload_File = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID('file')))
Upload_File.send_keys("YourFilePath")
```

Comment: ```python
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'visibility_of_element_located_by_id'
```

Comment: i have updated my answer. Now try and let me know if it is working or not. I have added one more import.

Comment: thanks for editing, I tried this, last error is solved but I receive TimeOutError.
here is the code and error:
```python
time.sleep(2)
Upload_File = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "file")))
Upload_File.send_keys("C:\\Users\\farzaniye\\Desktop\\New folder\\tt.txt")

```
```python
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
```